# Nontrivial solutions for a system of equations

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Consider $t:[0,1]^2\to R$ that is differentiable a.e. and satisfies  conditions (i)-(ii):

(i)

$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial t}{\partial t_1}(x,y)f(y\mid x)\,dy=0, \quad \forall x\in[0,1] \\
\int_0^1 \frac{\partial t}{\partial t_2}(x,y)f(x\mid y)\,dx=0, \quad \forall y\in[0,1]
$$

where $f$ is a continuously differentiable density function $f:[0,1]^2\to R_+$.

(ii)

$$
\frac{\partial t}{\partial t_1}\leq 0,   \quad  \text{if } x\geq y;  \qquad \frac{\partial t}{\partial t_1}\geq 0,   \quad  \text{if } x< y; \\
\frac{\partial t}{\partial t_2}\geq 0,   \quad  \text{if } x\geq y; \qquad  \frac{\partial t}{\partial t_2}\leq 0,   \quad  \text{if } x< y.
$$

The question is that without constructing a solution, how could I show that the system has a nontrivial solution such that $t$ is not a constant ?

Thanks.